# Artisan::call UP wont affect via URL

Tags: call, laravel-artisan

How would you solve the following problem?

When I go to `https://myweb.local/artisan/site-down` my site is sent to maintenance mode, which is to be expected. My route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/artisan/site-up', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('up');
    return redirect()->back();
});

Route::get('/artisan/site-down', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('down');
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

If I now want to wake up the page from maintenance mode (via URL), i.e. call `https://myweb.local/artisan/site-up`, then the first route is not processed, which makes sense. Now, on my local machine I can just fetch the page from maintenance mode via command line (`php artisan up`) but how can I do that on the remote server if I don't have SSH access?

Alternatively I could delete the "down" file via FTP from the "storrage" folder and the site would be fetched from sleep, but that is not a nice method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I could use the following method to solve this problem by attaching a Secret:

```
Route::get('/artisan/site-down', function() {
$exitCode = Artisan::call('down --secret="123456789"');
return redirect()->back();
});
```

Then call `https://myweb.local/123456789` and then finally call `https://myweb.local/artisan/site-up` to wake up the site from maintenance mode.

I'm still interested in other possible approaches though?